# postgres copiar tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Hola tengo una base de datos en postgres 9 la cual tengo 139 tablas pero necesito copiar solo 7 tablas que son las nuevas para meterlas en otra base de datos, Si se pueden diganme como  se los agradezco Gracias.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Se mas especifico con los que necesitas, para que te puedan ayudar.
Si vas a migrar las tablas con la misma estructura puedes exportar las tablas a archivos csv y luego importarlas en la otra base de datos, o user el pgAdmin para exportar solo la data de las tablas en un archivo plano y asi insertar la data en tu otra base de datos

Comment: Si usted lee bien e interpreta lo que estoy pubicando entenderá lo que quiero. No entiendo su comentario . Estoy siendo BIEN CLARO . QUIERO COPIAR SOLO UN GRUPOS DE TABLAS DE UNA BASE DE DATOS . PARA IMPORTARLAS A UNA BASE DE DATOS DISTINTA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la linea de comandos:

**EXPORTAR TABLA**

```
pg_dump -i -h [servidor] -p 5432 -U [usuario] -t [tabla] -F p -b -v -f "mitabla.sql" [basedatos]
```

**IMPORTAR TABLA**

```
psql -h [servidor] -d [basedatos] -U [usuario] -f "mitabla.sql"
```

Comment: Y si son varias tablas que quiero exportar ? Tengo que hacerlo con cada una ?

Comment: En nombre de la tabla puedes utilizar un patrón de acuerdo al nombre para exportar todas ellas. [http://www.damianculotta.com.ar/bases-de-datos/backup-de-tablas-especificas-en-postgresql]