# Copiar tabla en postgres si ya existe

Tags: postgresql

He conseguido sacar la tabla que necesito gracias a la pregunta:  [postgres copiar tablas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92277/postgres-copiar-tablas)

```
sudo pg_dump -i -h server-address -p 5432 -U postgres -t product_attribute_line -F p -b -v -f "product_attribute_line.sql" database-name
```

Mi problema viene cuando hago

```
psql -d database -U postgres -f product_attribute_line.sql
```

, y es el error es que está creada ya:

```
psql:product_attribute_line.sql:1486: ERROR:  constraint "product_attribute_line_write_uid_fkey" for relation "product_attribute_line" already exists
```

Sería más fácil si pudiera eliminarla para crearla de nuevo, pero el problema está en que si la elimino la base de datos ya no funcionará más.

He intentado hacer un `insert into` pero no consigo que funcione, tampoco funciona al hacer un import/export con el pg_admin. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice es que ya hay un constrain con ese nombre debes eliminarlo antes de hacer el psql o quitarlo del script que vas a subir.

Para eliminar un constrain solo debe dar clic sobre el la tabla, en el signa mas que aparece a un lado, luego donde dice constraints y dar clic derecho -eliminar sobre el que tegenera conflicto.

Esto asumiendo que usas pgadmin III